# Exclude a folder when publishing MVC aplication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm using visual studio publish feature to publish my MVC application.
And I have this folder called Images to hold the user files.

When I do a publish I don't want that folder to be deleted and recreated because that will cause to loose my data.In other words I want to keep that folder as it was after publishing.

I tried editing the pubxml and all nothing works.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the build action of the folder.

Solution Explorer 
1) Right click on the images folder
2) select properties

Find the "build actions" property.

Set it to something other than "content". It might be "exclude" but I don't remember.